# Page(s) Unresponsive in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

In Windows XP2, running Google Chrome (too long to responds), I often receive a message "Page(s) Unresponsive" asking me to either "kill pages" or "wait".

I already reinstalled it, but the same problem persists.

[image]

My PC specs:

- Intel P4 1.8GHz
- 1 GB Ram
- 64mb BGA
- 5 GB free HD space (In System Partition)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What site is it trying to load? Try changing your homepage to Google. Do you get the same thing? Need more information.

Comment: Do you still experience the issue even with a [new profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059)?

Comment: Arran : I try to open facebook too long to respond, I try to open another site, but it's the same.
I guess it's for all sites.

--
Iglvzx : I googled about new profile & try, but the problem persists.

Comment: @PerdanaPutra Can you try [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable)? Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @iglvzx : portable?
what about my processor & Ram, whether it's possible?
thank's, before, I will try it

Comment: @PerdanaPutra There should be no problems. The portable version is just one that installs itself into a single folder, making no other changes to the operating system. I am trying to see if the problem is with your specific installation of Google Chrome, or if it is bigger.

Comment: are there any other factors you could tell us about your "net" that could effect general responce time?  big hosts blocking files, aggressive or dual net filtering security? Poor connection to wirless signals , or even a phone modem?

Comment: It's possible that the PC isn't powerful enough and needs more time to load the pages. How long have you waited?

Comment: @iglvzx : i dont know, the problem persists .. Now i choose Mozilla 12 to browsing

Comment: @Psycogeek : if i browsing with other browser, its ok .. but i donk know if i using chrome that isue is appear again

Comment: @RandolphWest : Its too long, around 5 minutes, but if i using other browser to load sane site, it directly open the paga

Comment: That is strange indeed. Perhaps it's a plugin that's causing it to go crazy.

Comment: Which version you are using of Chrome?

Comment: Also see this [support page](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113910) from Google.

Comment: Chrome version? Which extensions are you using?

Comment: I agree with the general consensus that Chrome is a memory hog, and even if it doesn't solve your problem, I'd ditch it and go with Firefox (unless you get another gig or two of RAM)

Comment: Yeah, google crome version please?

Comment: How many plugins and extensions do you have installed? Check `chrome://plugins/` and `chrome://extensions/` and they will state the number at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a a few common causes for this behavior. Some are easier to fix than others.

## Performance/Overload

The most common cause of the hang is that the browser/system is overloaded.

(While in the past people would often sell old, obsolete computers as "Internet/surfing/browsing/email/etc, systems", the fact is that these days, you need a pretty hefty system to even just browse the Internet anymore because many sites use a bevy of plugins as such like Flash, Silverlight, WebGL, JavaScript, advanced HTML5 functions, etc. As a result, even a P4 1.8GHz system can come to a crawl when trying to render and display more than a few beefy sites.)

To determine if the browser is overloaded, open the *Task Manager* (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Esc</kbd>) and view the CPU load (do so while Chrome is closed, then again when you get the hang). If you see that the usage is high, then what is likely happening is that the browser is trying to render pages that the system is having trouble handling.

In this case, there are a few things to try that can help.

- Upgrading hardware (CPU, memory, video-card in particular) one way to resolve this issue. Of course this is not necessarily practical or even always possible.
- Another way to deal with such pages is to keep as few tabs open as possible. Even when a tab is in the background, they still consume resources, and depending on the page and the JavaScript and plugins it uses, they can be bogging the rest of the browser (and whole system for that matter) down.
- In general, it is advisable to keep as few extensions and plugins installed as possible. The fact is that the more extensions you have, the slower the whole browser gets because it has so much more processing to do. The same goes for plugins, though they usually only apply to pages that include them while extensions are *always* active. You should uninstall any extensions and plugins you don't need, and disable any you *do* need, but don't use (very) regularly.
- Keep your extensions and plugins updated. Not only do updates fix security issues, but they often include performance improvements as well, which can be anywhere from insignificant to dramatic.

  - You can update extensions by opening `chrome://extensions`, clicking *Developer Mode*, and then *Update Extensions* (**NB** it only updates enabled extensions, which is another reason to keep as few as needed)
  - Plugins need to be updated manually, but you can use [some tools](https://superuser.com/questions/429215/how-can-i-be-sure-that-browser-plugins-are-secure/429252#429252) to help track them to simplify the task
- Disable JavaScript (by default). Turning JavaScript off altogether will, not surprisingly, greatly increase performance and reduce the load on the system, thus allowing pages to be rendered faster. You can turn it off by going to `chrome://chrome/settings/content` (it may be different for different versions of Chrome, but will usually be under *Settings->Content Settings->JavaScript* in general).

  - Note however, that JavaScript is pretty much essential for many sites these days, so turning it off "whole-hog" isn't a universal fix. Instead, what you will want to do is to either turn it off by default and then set exceptions to allow it on certain pages, or to turn it on by default and set exceptions to block it on certain pages.
- Like with JavaScript, plugins will bog the browser down, but unlike JavaScript, you don't have to turn plugins on or off (or even manage block/allow lists), you can control plugins *per-element* by setting plugins to *Click-to-Play*. Normally, plugins are automatically loaded and run, but that is not always desirable (or efficient). You can set Chrome to display a placeholder for plugins which you can then either click to run it, click the `☒` to remove the object, or just ignore it. You can do this in the same page as with JavaScript (`chrome://chrome/settings/content`), though in older versions of Chrome, you may need to enable the feature first in `chrome://flags`.

  - You can also accomplish selective plugin- (usually Flash-)blocking with [extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/block%20flash) (but don't go overboard; pick one or two good ones; using a dozen will just bog the system down again).
- Another factor that often causes Chrome tabs to hang is due to ads. Some sites are just awful. They have pop-ups, pop-unders, Flash ads, Silverlight ads, countless JavaScript ads, image ads, video ads, and so on. Things are not as bad as they were in the "early days" of the Internet when you could get caught up in a so-called "pornado storm", but the Internet is still quite laden with CPU- and bandwidth-hogging ads. Installing an ad-blocker will help to squelch the flood of ads to reduce the impact they make on the browser. You can do this by using a [HOSTS file](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm) and/or by installing an ad-blocking [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/block%20ads) (again, don't go overboard).

## Bugs

Another cause of hangs can be bugs.

- Bugs can be present in the browser itself, and updating it can help. For Google Chrome, go to *Wrench menu->About* to have it auto-update.
- Bugs can also be present in plugins and extensions. For this, refer back to the previous section on updating them.
- Bugs can also be present in webpages (e.g., a piece of JavaScript with an infinite loop or AJAX blocked on a resource).

  - If the page is the problem, one options of course is to contact the webmaster and let them know about the problem and wait for them to fix it.
  - Another options is to view the [Google Cache](http://www.googleguide.com/cached_pages.html) or [Internet Archive/"Way Back Machine"](http://archive.org/web/web.php) of the page which may be from before the bug was introduced. In fact, with the Google Cache, you can click the *text-only* link in the header to view the page much fast by getting only the text of the page without images, plugins, scripts, etc.

## Network

Network issues can also cause Chrome to hang like that. For example, if the page is blocking on a resource, and the site is down, the network is congested, your connection is being throttled, etc. then it can sit there waiting and waiting. In this case, you would need to check your Internet connection, though usually, this sort of problem will be intermittent. If you are experiencing it regularly like you said, then it is probably not the network connection.

## Aliens and Gremlins

Finally, there are other, miscellaneous, obscure, esoteric, niche, oddball causes that can make tabs hang. These are the freaks that have no rhyme or reason and cannot be explained except perhaps by soothsayers and warlocks.

One such example is that a few months ago, a *very small* handful sites (e.g., Chrome Webstore, VirusTotal) stopped working for me. They would *very occasionally* load, but would often sit there stuck (usually waiting on some `.js` Google Adsense files to load), with the throbber spinning and/or throwing up an *unresponsive* prompt. I tried everything from enabling everything to disabling everything, but nothing worked. Eventually I found that by disabling the DNS-prefetching function, they started working again. The real kicker is that the DNS-prefetching function had already been enabled for some time while the sites were still working, so it must have been a **change in the pages** that caused the issue (though other people were still able to load the sites, so either they had the function disabled or were using different browsers or newer versions).

The point is that one of the "downside-effects" of the software-as-a-service paradigm is that things that were working just fine can suddenly break and stop working without you having made any changes at all. This gives rise to a whole host of bizarre and unexplainable causes of problems.

Answer (score 2):

1. if you test your ASP, JSP or PHP code in localhost, check your javascript code, In my experience, bad javascript loop will make chrome unresponsive.
2. check your Anti-virus software, try to stop it and open chrome again.
3. uninstall chrome and download a different version, install again.
4. maybe RAM is lower. show your `Windows Task Manager`, see the RAM and CPU usage. (In my PC, each page cost 10-35M RAM, I think 1 GB Ram is enough, so this is the 4th possible)

Answer (score 2):

try to check extension for google chrome flash, flash extensions this could be causing us to google chrome error.

1. Go to Google chrome.
2. In the address bar (where typing a web address) type the command:
   about:plugins
3. Cari the word "Flash" and click "Disable"
4. Restart google chrome and see if the problem can be resolved.

Comment: This fixes it for me every time, but let me change your method:  right click in the title bar of Chrome and choose task manager instead, then scroll down to Flash the plugin and click on it, then End Process.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your PC is running low on memory. Chrome uses so many processes.

Try to avoid too many tabs opened and don't use too many add-ons in Chrome, because it will cause too many processes and a crash will occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the steps below:

1. Use the Chrome Javascript debugger to pause (breaks running code) during the unresponsiveness. It takes some timing, but it should break in the middle of whatever is running too long.
2. You can then use the debugger controls to step around and see what is looping unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have multiple Flash Players installed. If yes, follow these steps:

1. remove Adobe Flash plugin and Shockwave.
2. restart your browser.

If when you have only one Flash Player installed on your system you still have the problem, try removing it too.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0gTJtvPL6c). Same problem he had. Right click on the shortcut of `Google Chrome>propeties` under `shortcut` tab change the Target setting. Don't delete the path just go to the end of the target and give space and type `-no-sanbox`. It fix the problem for him may be it will do the same for you.

See this [Google help Page](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/UbZHxI3RiHk) they have the same problem and there are many solution to it.

**1:** Run a virus and malware scan and make sure your PC is clean. 
You can use [combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) to scan for malware and trojans.

**2:** Open the Taskmanger and kill all Google process and then launch the Chrome and try to load the pages.

**3:** Try kaspersky [TDSSKiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208283363) may be it would help you to find out the problem.

As I read on any article that

`For 'Page Kill' in Chrome and in general for pages that become unresponsive there, we suggest, download TDSSKiller.exe from Kaspersky Lab install and run it. There is a file which gets infected with TDSS rootkit and this fixes up Google Chrome being unresponsive.`
and user had respond there that they got back to worked with Chrome.

From [article](http://dummy-essentials.blogspot.in/2009/10/fix-google-chrome-aw-snap-error.html).

Comment: thank's for you Answer,
I tried running it with -no-sandbox, but that didn't work either.I see in task manager if I add-no-sandbox, it's wearing a large memory capacity to process.
please give me other advice

Comment: I Googled and find some people have problem due to Malware and a virus named `Alureon.H`. Please try to scan your computer for malware or any virus. If you have the antivirus run a scan now or download the [msessential](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials/download) and also run a scan through [combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/). Both are free.

Comment: Also disable the `Ad-Block` and see if it works and try with `--no-sandbox`

Comment: Down voter please tell me what is wrong in my answer?????

Comment: See edits now and check if it help and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Something to try : Use Chrome's equivalent of Safe Mode by opening an Incognito window, to temporarily disable extensions ([more info](http://googlesystem.blogspot.fr/2010/02/google-chrome-safe-mode.html)).

If this helps, then it is a matter of a bad plugin. To find out which one, click on the Wrench, then click "View Background Pages" ([more info](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1184722)). A plugin gone crazy will usually take 100% CPU or lots of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome has unique memory management. Every tab in consumes memory. When two or more tabs are opened and consume memory, it could possibly cause a crash.

These issues obviously can't be solved right now. Just wait for the latest Google Chrome version.

Sometimes I got that problem on my laptop with specification 512 MB or RAM, but it rarely happened on my PC with 2 GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

OK, until they finally update Google Chrome try the following:

open cmd (from the task bar) and type the following:

> ipconfig /flushdns

If that doesn't help, updating your RAM will help. Get another GB of RAM it'll help you in many situations not just this one, promise ;)

Comment: *> If that doesn't help, updating your RAM will help.*   NOT practical; at all. (It must be nice to be rich enough to just indiscriminately throw money at problems.)

Comment: It is......... :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be too that it is using too much memory. You can check how much memory Chrome uses in detail using the included Task Manager which can be opened via "Shift+ESC".

Per default Chrome spawns one process per tab, that has a lot overhead of course. You can change the behavior by using the

```
--single-process
```

switch, that will make Chrome handle the tabs like every other browser: only one process. That should reduce the memory usage.

Comment: The `--single-process` switch is not supported and causes numerous compatibility, stability, and security issues (you even get [a wawheng](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MDDaJ.png) to that effect when you use it). It is a meant to be used a diagnostic step, **not** a general-purpose flag.