# Google Chrome completely unresponsive

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Pages load indefinitely and most of the time I get this error:

[image]

Pressing 'wait' or 'kill pages' does **nothing**, I have to close the error window from the upper right button.

What I mean by 'completely unresponsive':

- I have multiple accounts: **none** works.
- Things like Settings (chrome://settings/) or About (chrome://chrome/) sections are also inaccessible
- Incognito window is also unresponsive
- Creating a new profile starts a new page (chrome://settings/createProfile) that also keeps loading indefinitely

This is not a duplicate of [Page(s) Unresponsive in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/q/426516/162573), the pages do not load slowly, they do not load at all, not even the settings, I have no overload, I have enough ram, the other browsers, including a portable Chromium and the Chromium-based Comodo Dragon are not affected by this. I can start 4 or 5 browsers at the same time and only Google Chrome is unresponsive.

As far as I can tell I was using the present latest version of the browser (or at least a very recent one): as I said, About (chrome://chrome/) is not accessible! :) After downloading and installing the latest version, no change. After uninstalling completely and installing last version, no change.

I cannot access the addons and the plugins.

---

EDIT:

- Disabling addons and plugins as specified in [this](https://superuser.com/a/822449/162573) answer didn't help. Deleting the folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\` (removing all profiles) didn't help. The fresh profile is still affected.
- It seems in fact that Chromium portable is somewhat affected by a problem that may or may not be related to this one: when windows/tabs are loading for the first time they are slow to respond, but once loaded they work fine, opening links and other pages as normal. This slowness of windows when first opening the browser is also present in SRIron and Google Chrome Canary (but not in the other Chromium-based browsers that I tested, Opera and Comodo Dragon).

Comment: See if [How to open Google Chrome with extensions disabled / turned off?](http://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off) helps.

Comment: @DavidPostill - it does not. that is about addons, which are userprofile specific. my problem affects all profiles

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/822449/337631

Comment: @DavidPostill - thank you for your instructive answer. although it did not solve that problem, i liked the part ' /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1' which fixes a display issue

Comment: just wondering how you have solved this issue !!

Comment: @Frankenstein - Old post now. Didn't fixed it at the time I guess, but I'm not affected by this anymore, and I don't remember why, possibly I even reinstalled Windows, or replaced Chrome with Chromium, I have to test this when I boot into Windows (which I seldom do, as I prefer Linux). If I bump into it again I'll report back here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a software named as CCleaner. I think you should run that software and make clean and registry clean after uninstalling chrome. And then Re-Install.. And Make sure you have antivirus software.

Comment: did all that, not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Just got this problem on the last update to Chrome 47, on both Win 7 Home and Win 7 Professional machines.  An interim step to restore some functionality is to change the filename of chrome (e.g. to chrome..exe) and have your shortcut target the newly named file. This enables you to open chrome and edit settings. Then (on both my systems) going into settings and disabling hardware acceleration, then changing the filename back to chrome.exe gives a functional chrome installation. At this point my systems still worked after re enabling hardware acceleration.

Comment: You can edit your answer to include those additional details using the `edit` link above your usercard.

Comment: "Not really a solution" - I can't really find answers, that contained statements like that, very helpful considering you expect it to actually break functionality.